# Bridge Boardgame Night v1.0

Tags: discussion, community-event

There has been some discussion around the idea of playing some boardgames together, so let's try some!

We'll probably use [Tabletop Simulator](http://berserk-games.com/) to play, so if you want to participate, make sure to get a copy of that. TTS will run on pretty much anything and while it is available though Humble and other retailers, I'd strongly suggest getting Steam copy as that would allow us to use content from the game's [Steam Workshop page](http://steamcommunity.com/app/286160/workshop/).

## Games we'll be playing: Star Fluxx, Forbidden Island, and Superfight (sans the R deck)

## Time and Date: [April 10, 8-10:00pm EST](http://a.chronus.eu/16B5700) ([convert](http://everytimezone.com/#2015-4-10,720,c8l))

## Players: TBD

Since most of the games picked have a generous player count, we'll likely have some spots for people to jump in and out of games during the evening.

**Reserved spots:**

- RedRiderX
- TheAce
- Unionhawk
- You???

If you'd like your spot reserved, let me know in chat.

Comment: My vote is [4 player chess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaMumawHFAI).

Comment: Tables will be flipped!

Comment: Also a note, 8 players is a hard maximum. That's the most players the game will allow.

Comment: Too bad Tabletop Simulator doesn't have Bridge. It would be so appropriate.

Comment: Next time maybe not at 2AM for CEST? :( I want to play all of these games

Answer (score 6):

## Munchkin Deluxe

Number of players: 3+

Game Length: 1-3 hours

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=399809092)(broken atm) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1927/munchkin)

> Go down in the dungeon. Kill everything you meet. Backstab your friends and steal their stuff. Grab the treasure and run.
>   Admit it. You love it.
>
> Munchkin is the mega-hit card game about dungeon adventure . . . with none of that stupid roleplaying stuff. You and your friends compete to kill monsters and grab magic items. And what magic items! Don the Horny Helmet and the Boots of Butt-Kicking. Wield the Staff of Napalm . . . or maybe the Chainsaw of Bloody Dismemberment. Start by slaughtering the Potted Plant and the Drooling Slime, and work your way up to the Plutonium Dragon . . .
>
> And it's illustrated (in full color!) by John Kovalic!
>
> Fast-playing and silly, Munchkin can reduce any roleplaying group to hysteria. And, while they're laughing, you can steal their stuff.

Comment: "That item does not exist. It may have been removed by the author."

Comment: Nooooo! I've been betrayed!

Comment: Sounds like it was a DMCA takedown. Can't say I'm surprised, and I don't really blame them.

Answer (score 4):

## Cards against Humanity

Number of players: 4 − 30

Game Length: 30 minutes

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=356805139) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/50381/cards-against-humanity)

> Cards Against Humanity is a party game for horrible people. Unlike most of the party games you've played before, Cards Against Humanity is as despicable and awkward as you and your friends.
>
> The game is simple. Each round, one player asks a question from a black card, and everyone else answers with their funniest white card.

**Note:** This game is not for the easily offended, so I wouldn't be surprised if anyone vetos this.

**Video is NSFW!**

Comment: +1! I would come just for this but I don't have TTS.

Comment: I likely won't be joining for the game night, but I'd be wary about this game. In particular, this can be a very inflammatory game if you don't know the people you are playing with very well. The card combinations often can be very offensive and touch on sensitive topics. I love the game, but -1 here just because I'm not sure an "anyone can join" game of this playing online is the best idea.

Answer (score 4):

### Superfight

Number of players: 3+

Game Length: 30 minutes

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=404558514) [Link 2](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=404234058) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/139443/superfight)

> Superfight is party game of super powers and super problems.
>
> The game is all about arguing with your friends about ridiculous fights.

Think cards against humanity except superheroes.

Comment: Any concerns about CAH probably apply here to at least some extent (though it's probably a much smaller extent)

Answer (score 4):

### Betrayal at House on the Hill

Number of players: 3-6
Game Length: It could take a couple of hours

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=261027555)(broken atm) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-house-hill)

> Betrayal at House on the Hill quickly builds suspense and excitement as players explore a haunted mansion of their own design, encountering spirits and frightening omens that foretell their fate. With an estimated one hour playing time, Betrayal at House on the Hill is ideal for parties, family gatherings or casual fun with friends.
>
> Betrayal at House on the Hill is a tile game that allows players to build their own haunted house room by room, tile by tile, creating a new thrilling game board every time. The game is designed for three to six people, each of whom plays one of six possible characters.
>
> Secretly, one of the characters betrays the rest of the party, and the innocent members of the party must defeat the traitor in their midst before it’s too late! Betrayal at House on the Hill will appeal to any game player who enjoys a fun, suspenseful, and strategic game.

Comment: I should mention that I don't actually own the game, but a friend does.  I don't know if the Tabletop Simulator version also includes the scenario book or not, which is kinda vital.

Comment: I tried running the mod you linked to, from the description it doesn't seem to have the books included and this mod in particular seems to have some dead links in it and is broken for me.

Comment: Also sidenote: Because of the amount of paper and books to manage in a game like this it might be better suited to a [Roll20](http://roll20.net/) adaptation.

Comment: Something I didn't really consider is that the loyalists and defector(s) don't know the full extent the others scenario.  One person can't reasonably know both sides and still play.

Comment: Yeah that sort of thing could be managed in TTS but would be much easier in Roll20 I think.

Answer (score 3):

## Forbbiden Island

Number of players: 2 − 4

Game Length: 30 minutes

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=382321893) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/65244/forbidden-island)

> Forbidden Island is a visually stunning 'cooperative' board game. Instead of winning by competing with other players like most games, everyone must work together to win the game.
>
> Players take turns moving their pawns around the 'island', which is built by arranging the many beautifully screen-printed tiles before play begins. As the game progresses, more and more island tiles sink, becoming unavailable, and the pace increases. Players use strategies to keep the island from sinking, while trying to collect treasures and items. As the water level rises, it gets more difficult- sacrifices must be made.

Answer (score 3):

## The Resistance

Number of players: 5 − 10

Game Length: 30 minutes

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=371505586) [Boardgamegeek link](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41114/resistance)

> The Resistance is a party game of social deduction. The Resistance is inspired by Mafia/Werewolf, yet it is unique in its core mechanics, which increase the resources for informed decisions, intensify player interaction, and eliminate player elimination.

Comment: This is an awesome game.

Answer (score 3):

### Fluxx 4+

Number of players: 2 − 6
Game Length: Varies, but usually 15-45 minutes
[Workshop Link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=260568016) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/258/fluxx)

Fluxx is a game with simple rules:  Draw 1, Play 1.

Or is it?  Well, no, because the rules are constantly in flux.
What's the goal of the game?  Whatever the most recently played goal card is!
What are the current rules?  Take a look at the table.  It starts out Draw 1. Play 1... but it could easily be Draw 4, Play 3, Hand Limit 1!

Note that this is version 4 and not version 5 (which came out in October).  I've never actually played version 4, though.

There are other variations of the game on TTS, such as...

### Star Fluxx+

[Workshop link](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=260573768&searchtext=fluxx) [Boardgamegeek link](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/102104/star-fluxx)

The more advanced editions of Fluxx are more complicated than the original and take longer to play.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why but the video is displaying in only a portion of the Youtube window.  The video didn't look like this when I originally watched it some time back.